# I installed the Civicrm module on drupal but it s not showing in the navigation bar

Tags: civicrm

I just installed the CiviCRM module on a Drupal website, but I can only find the setting pages for the module.

I have already assigned the necessary permissions to the site administrator.

How I can access the CiviCRM module pages?

Comment: I've seen this happen before. Just add the link manually.

Comment: I had this happen to me once or twice but not since CiviCRM version 3.4 I think. You can easily add the link manually as Malks suggest. Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Installing the CiviCRM module on Drupal requires a few more steps than just enabling the module itself. Check out how to do this in the [Drupal Installation Guide for CiviCRM](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC40/Installation+and+Upgrades) for the version you're using.

Comment: You may be interested in supporting the new [CiviCRM SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77367/civicrm?referrer=8gfMpihOSETXeNHrjdyxXQ2) site

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

If you've followed the full install profile guide that vgardner linked to and you're still not seeing the menu, you can try flushing your drupal cache.  You can manually edit the admin menu.  You might also want to try replacing the default toolbar module with administration menu module (https://drupal.org/project/admin_menu). Mine picked the civicrm admin entry right away (or after a cache flush)

Answer (score 1):

If you go to www.yourwebsite.org/civicrm and you got an error, your CiviCRM is not installed correctly and you need to follow the guide mentionned by vgardner.

Otherwise, it's just that CiviCRM will not appear in Drupal top bar using default toolbar menu, you need to disable toolbar and use admin_menu module instead.